# how do I track changes in file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

suppose the below text is present in the file

```
1.a=2
2.b=3
3.print(a+b)
```

if i change the value of b to 5, how to print that in this line this field is changed in python

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  You can't change a file while its running.  What you are talking about sounds like a job for a source code management system, like `git`.  You could check in version 1, then `git diff` tells you what has changed since then.

Comment: If you change the value of a file, the only way python would know that is if it had access to a previous version of the file. There are file management tools like `git` that you can use to track files. Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: I mean to say is there any way i can create a version control system to track any type of file changes

Comment: That's exactly what `git` is for.  You don't need to write your own.

Comment: I know that, but I want to write my own, is there any way i can get the git code that does this

Comment: git is an open-source tool. Just download its source if you want to.

Comment: 1) you need to keep copies of how the file was before each change and 2) https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm

Comment: @MarkSetchell that step 2 is for linux, can i do that for a python program?

Comment: `difflib` maybe? https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

Comment: I thought the same, it doesn't work exactly like the unix, but it might do the job

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use gif for version control of your source code and some library like [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#tutorial-label) to be able to interact from python.

Comment: I want to avoid using git, something like this python program should be stand alone